Azure analytics custom log table receives ContainerLog logs
I have a kubernates cluster in azure cloud that sends me some logs information to my table ContainerLog now I am trying to send part of these logs to a custom log table.
The sample flow would be like:
MyApp (write stdout logs) -> Log analytics (gets this stdout logs) -> (sends to table ) ContainerLog -> transformation (for especific LogEntry) -> MyCustomLogTable_CL (should receive transformed data).
I've tried to create a custom log table along with data collection rule (DCR) where the data source is my ContainerLog table and the destination is my log analytics specifically MyCustomLogTable_CL.
No success, because no logs comming to MyCustomLogTable_CL table.

The process you are following is correct when you want to send some of the log entries to the custom log table.
Check below mentioned scenarios and try executing the query again.
Make sure that the table has created successfully with the relevant schema according to the container log entries.

Go to the attached DCR and check the data sources configuration source and destination as shown below.

Once everything is properly given, run below query to transfer the logs from one to another.
ContainerLog
| where LogEntry contains "TimeGenerated"
| project LogEntry, TimeGenerated //custom table fields


Also check if you have a necessary permission to access the container logs from cluster and place it in log analytics workspace.
